# Why isalpha() doesn't work?

Tags: python

Python 3.4.3

I'm reading data from Excel-file via **openpyxl**. E18 cell contains text 'переход'.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename='data.xlsx', read_only=True)
ws = wb.active
data = ws['E18'].value
print(data.isalpha())
```

Why it print False?

Comment: works for me too in Python 3.4.3, notes that no blanks in cell.

Comment: If you print data before checking `isalpha`. What does it look like?

Comment: What does `print(repr(data))` look like? There are probably *extra characters* there that may not be visible when printing `data` directly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it have an space at end:( `data.strip().isalpha()` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I created a similar spreadsheet with these values:

```
переход
'переход'
abc
'
```

It prints for each of the above respectively:

```
True
False
True
False
```

Does you data contain the ' character which is not alpha and therefor you get False?

```
print ("'".isalpha())
False
print ("переход".isalpha())
True
print ("'переход'".isalpha())
False
```